# How to add another quality video to jwplayer?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I added another quality for showing the video, but there is no choice of another quality in the video player

```
jwplayer("player2").setup({
        image: "https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/tkM1zvBq/poster.jpg?width=720",
        "type": "video/mp4",
        "sources": [{
            "file": "http://*:1935/vod/volikogu_1080p.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
            "label": "1080p"
        }, {
            "file": "http://*:1935/vod/volikogu_720p.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
            "label": "720p"
        }, {
            "file": "http://*:1935/vod/volikogu_360p.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
            "label": "360p"
        }],
        "label": "H.264 320px"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a few things in the above config that could be causing poor behavior in the player. First off, you have `type` on the top level when it should be on the same level as your `source` objects in the `sources` array. It also appears as though type is `hls` and not `video/mp4` (based on the `m3u8` extension).

Does the following setup change any behavior for you?

```
jwplayer("player2").setup({
        image: "https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/tkM1zvBq/poster.jpg?width=720"
        "sources": [{
            "file": "http://*:1935/vod/volikogu_1080p.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
            "label": "1080p",
            "type": "hls"
        }, {
            "file": "http://*:1935/vod/volikogu_720p.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
            "label": "720p",
            "type": "hls"
        }, {
            "file": "http://*:1935/vod/volikogu_360p.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
            "label": "360p",
            "type": "hls"
        }]
});
```

If the type of your files *is* mp4 then replace `"type": "hls"` with `"type": "mp4"` in the above.

Comment: No, it does not work. I have no errors or other magazines

Answer (score 0):

You would be best served to have all of your child manifests in one single parent manifest. Do not put multiple m3u8's as different sources. Let the player or the browser change the quality based on a single master manifest. Also, your "label" and "type" attributes are not valid, I would remove them entirely.